# How can I divide an interval [start,end] into n points of equal distance?

Tags: java, math, intervals, divide

I have an interval from `start` to `end` where `start` and `end` are type `double`. I want to divide the interval into `n` points, where each two neighboring points are the same distance apart.
For example:

```
// Given closed interval [-3.14,3.14]:
start = -3.14
end = 3.14
n = 3

// The 3 points would be:
-3.14, 0.0, 3.14

// Where the distance between each two neighboring points is 3.14
```

Or:

```
// Given left-closed, right-open interval [0,1):
start = 0
end = 1
n = 4

// The 4 points would be:
0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75

// Where the distance between each two neighboring points is .25
```

I'm having trouble with this, appreciate any advice

Comment: `end - start / n` will give you the distance between your points. Can you go on your own from that?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca maybe I'm being picky, but it should be (end-start)/(n-1) for a closed interval

Comment: @RobertKock ah, I didn't notice that the two examples show different things and I focused on the second one only.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca If I use this formula with `start = -3.14` and `end = 3.14`, I will get  `2.09333333333`...I'm afraid I don't see how I could use this value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sorry, now I see it. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the logic you have shown so far the the `interval` sizes are:

- closed: `(end - start) / (n - 1)`
- open one side: `(end - start) / n`
- open both sides: `(end - start) / (n + 1)`

The initial left point is:

- closed on the left: `start`
- open on the left: `start + interval`.

All other points just add a `interval` on top